# Possible encoding issue when querying data using Azure Synapse

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have a Synapse Data Flow that transforms a JSON file into Delta table format and stores this in ADLS. The Data Flow extracts properties from the JSON file and records the data into its individual column in the Delta table.

When I query one the extracted columns through the linked ADLS in Synapse using a SQL query like so:

```
-- This is auto-generated code
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://storage-acount.dfs.core.windows.net/container/path/to/data/',
        FORMAT = 'DELTA'
    ) AS [result]
WHERE columnA = '27489d7s8a9-7d8s-9942-b38s-hj7889f98dd8d_WhfiInWWhJH8Hwhw-wu'
```

The records appear in the dataset.

However, if I use Notebook to load the data into a Pyspark dataframe, then query the data like so:

```
df.filter(col('columnA') == '27489d7s8a9-7d8s-9942-b38s-hj7889f98dd8d_WhfiInWWhJH8Hwhw-wu')
```

No results are returned.

If however, I do this:

```
df_filtered = df.filter(col("columnA").like("27489d7s8a9-7d8s-9942-b38s-hj7889f98dd8d_WhfiInWWhJH8Hwhw-wu"))
```

I get the expected records.

Or if I do this:

```
df_trimmed = df.withColumn("columnA_trimmed", trim(col("columnA")))
df_trimmed.filter(col('columnA_trimmed') == '27489d7s8a9-7d8s-9942-b38s-hj7889f98dd8d_WhfiInWWhJH8Hwhw-wu')
```

I also get results. Anyone know why this is?

Then length of the data is the same before and after trim.

I can do exact match in SQL against the linked ADLS:
[image: Exact match]

Querying using Pyspark using TRIM:
[image: Trimmed comparison]

Querying using Pyspark using LIKE:
[image: Comparison using like]

Comment: because of some spaces at the end or begin of the string it is not filtering. Check the data once again if it is having whitespace at the begin or end of the string.

Comment: I can't see any obvious whitespaces looking at the data. Also why would the SQL query return data if that was the case?

Comment: Perhaps SQL is using different collation/character set than the pyspark dataframe. Thus , whitespaces are automatically handled in sql. Can you check the length of the data from dataframe and compare it with sql result?

Comment: All counts are the same, please see screenshots in my main post.